# Changing Jest mock value between tests

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, vue.js, mocking, jestjs

I have a utility file that uses the following implementation with a vuex store:

```
// example.js

import store from '@/store';

[...]

export default function exampleUtil(value) {
  const user = store.state.user.current;
  [...]
}
```

In my test, I found that I can successfully mock the value of `user` in the following two ways:

**Manual mock**

```
// store/__mocks__/index.js

export default {
  state: {
    user: {
      current: {
        roles: [],
        isAdmin: false,
      },
    },
  },
};
```

or

**Mock function**

```
// example.spec.js

jest.mock('@/store', () => ({
  state: {
    user: {
      current: {
        roles: [],
        isAdmin: false,
      },
    },
  },
}));
```

The issue that I'm running into is that I want to be able to change the value of `current` between tests, such as changing `isAdmin` to true or updating the array for `roles`.

What is the best way to do this using Jest mocks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that the value of a mock can be changed inside a test directly after importing the mocked file.

Using the mock function example from above:

```
// example.spec.js

import store from '@/store'; // <-- add this

jest.mock('@/store', () => ({
  state: {
    user: {
      current: {
        roles: [],
        isAdmin: false,
      },
    },
  },
}));

it('should do things', () => {
  store.state.user.current.roles = ['example', 'another']; // <-- change mock value here
  [...]
});
```